# ST-Link V2 -- detected as USB mass storage device

Tags: stm32, stm32f1, st-link

I have a *"STM32VLDISCOVERY"* board ([link](https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32vldiscovery.html)) that I connected to my Windows PC.

This board has an integrated *"ST-Link V2"* programmer / debugger based on the *"STM32F103C8"* micro controller which actually communicates with the PC. But this micro controller is recognized as a *"USB mass storage device"*. In the *"Device manager"* it is located under `Disk drives/STM32`.

If i right click it and follow `Properties/Driver/Driver Deatils/` no ST drivers are listed. There are only some Windows default drivers used for this device:

[image]

Now I disconnect the board.

As stated in the documentation we have to only install the *"ST-Link V2"* Windows driver *"STSW-LINK009"* ([link](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stsw-link009.html?ecmp=tt9470_gl_link_feb2019&rt=tn&id=TN1235)) before we connect board to a PC.

I downloaded the driver, uncompressed it, and ran the `stlink_winusb_install.bat` script as the administrator. This installs the driver and should enable PC to communicate with *"STM32F103C8"* as it should.

I connect the board back to the workstation PC but nothing changes. Board is still treated as a *"USB mass storage device"*. In the *"Device manager"* it is still located under `Disk drives/STM32` and `Properties/Driver/Driver Deatils/` lists no ST drivers. Again only Windows drivers.

### ADD 1:

After the drivers were installed and board connected to the PC (as a *"USB mass storage device"*) I tried to flash the newest firmware to the board by using *"STSW-LINK007"* board firmware update utility ([link](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/development-tools/software-development-tools/stm32-software-development-tools/stm32-programmers/stsw-link007.html)) which fails to connect to the board:

[image]

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Does it work with STM32CubeIDE or STM32CubeProgrammer? Can you connect or debug the board using these programs?

Comment: @Tagli I added the ADD 1. Note that *"STSW-LINK007"* is specified on the official ST website as the tool for board flashing. And it fails to work.

Comment: I read in the "TN1235" that @Armandas posted in his answer that *"USB mass storage mode"* is supported in  *"ST-Link V2-1"*, *"ST-Link V2-A"*, *"ST-Link V2-B"* where *"ST-Link V2-A"* doesn't have support for *"virtual COM port"*. Is it possible that my 
*"STM32VLDISCOVERY"* board has a *"ST-Link V2-A"* and therefore can't connect through *"virtual COM port"*!? How can I verify which *"ST-Link"* version it has?

Comment: Is the board brand new? Is there any chance that someone re-programmed the on-board ST-Link MCU by mistake?

Answer (score 3):

ST-Link V2-1 implements USB mass storage interface to allow drag-and-drop programming.

If you must disable the mass storage interface, you can do it via the firmware update. From the [TN1235](https://www.st.com/resource/en/technical_note/tn1235-overview-of-stlink-derivatives-stmicroelectronics.pdf) document:

> On ST-LINK/V2-1 boards, it is possible to disable and restore the mass
> storage interface by means of the STLinkUpgrade applications (refer to
> Figure 1)

[image]

Comment: This makes sense! I thought that I have ST-Link V2! I did not realize that there is also a version ST-Link V2-1!

Comment: I tred using the *"STSW-LINK007"* ([link](https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/development-tools/software-development-tools/stm32-software-development-tools/stm32-programmers/stsw-link007.html)) to flash the board, but it fails to connect... Check **ADD 1** added to my question.